# How to add some value into variable of advice in aspect class

Tags: java, events, aspectj

This is quite odd but I really need this ... I have this code

```
@Aspect
public class SomeAspect {

    SomeObject someObject = null;

    @Pointcut("something")
    public void somePoint() {
    }

    @Before("somePoint()")
    public void beforeSomePoint() {
    }

    @After("somePoint()")
    public void afterSomePoint() {
        someObject.hello();
    }

    public void waitForEvent(SomeEvent event) {
        someObject = event.getObject();
    }
}
```

So basically I have pointcut and two advices, I have a method which is listening to some event which is fired in my application. I get object from that event I am interested in and I initialize `someObject` variable in `waitForEvent` method. This works and I am sure that `someObject` is passed correctly into `waitForEvent` method.

The point is that I need to operate on that object I got in the body of advice method like `someObject.hello()` but it seems to me that it is still null even I know that event is fired before actual execution of the `afterSomePoint` advice.

I am not using Spring or any other related framework. I am using pure Java + AspectJ, annotated version.

How do I pass some object into advice from *outside*?

Thank you a lot

Answer (score 1):

Hi are you sure that someObj is still null?

Here is the result for my experiment:

**I change someObject to String**.

```
@Aspect
public class SomeAspect {

    String someObject = null;

    @Pointcut("Call( * init(..) )")
    public void somePoint() {
    }

    @Before("somePoint()")
    public void beforeSomePoint() {
    }

    @After("somePoint()")
    public void afterSomePoint() {
        System.out.println(someObject);
    }

    public void waitForEvent(String event) {
        someObject = event;
    }
}
```

In my main program:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

SomeAspect a = Aspects.aspectOf(SomeAspect.class);
a.waitForEvent("Event!!");

Child c = new Child();
c.init(); //The advice will be triggered here!!

}
```

This way, afterSomePoint() advice is triggered, and "Event!!" is printed out

I think you can use Aspects.aspectOf(SomeAspect.class) to get the aspect instance, and pass it to the framework. If you new the SomeAspect, it will create another instance apart from the one already in the VM

Reference: eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/progguide/semantics-aspects.html

> Unlike class expressions, aspects are not instantiated with new
>   expressions. Rather, **aspect instances are automatically created** to cut
>   across programs. A program can get a reference to an aspect instance
>   using the static method aspectOf(..)

Comment: Hi, I am using some other techniques which may do difference when execution the code. That code in the second post is not complete. E.g. I am using custom dependency injection for `someObject` which can change a lot ... I am not using that `c.init()` thing since I am not able to execute it on my own.

Comment: Hi~ can I know how is  `@Pointcut("something")` defined?
This determines where the advice is woven.

And can you print out some log in ur advice & waitForEvent() ?

Comment: Is it possible `waitForEvent()` is called several times?

and before the advice is executed, someObject is set to null again?

Comment: it looks like this `@Pointcut("execution(@org.junit.Test * *())")` it picks all methods which are annotated with @Test from JUnit, I need to do some operation before test method is executed. As I said, I am using another framework which gives me `event` dynamically into @Aspect.

Comment: I do not know what you are asking me :) I have no problem with that anymore since I solved it as you can see in my second post and it seems to be ok.

Comment: One thought!

As you pointed out, if you change the someObject fiedl to static, then there is no problem.

I'd guess, the Aspect is not singleton in your environment, and 1 aspect receive the event, and 1 aspect run the advice, and don't share the same member variable.

Comment: ok~ if you have no interest in studying this issue, then I have no further comment :) I just thought you want to know the real reason.

cheers~

Comment: Yeah ... but even it is not singleton, which I do not know at all if it is or not, I am  registering that class as so called "observer" in that framework which observes these events I am waiting for in the method. So that @Aspect _is_ singleton but in other meaning ...

Comment: just try print the `this` in `waitForEvent()` and the advice, and you'll see if there is only 1 aspect.

Comment: good point, I'll report the results to you once done ... thank you for the interest. I think that I am combining multiple approaches so it can do weird things.

Comment: I think you can use `Aspects.aspectOf(SomeAspect.class)` to get the aspect instance, and pass it to the framework. If you `new` the SomeAspect, it will create another instance apart from the one already in the VM

Comment: I'm not sure if you new your own aspect...just a quick guess.

Reference: http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/progguide/semantics-aspects.html

Unlike class expressions, aspects are not instantiated with new expressions. Rather, aspect instances are automatically created to cut across programs. A program can get a reference to an aspect instance using the static method aspectOf(..)

Answer (score 0):

Oh this is very funny ...

I just made that variable static and it seems it works. Is this some kind of magic? Is this the way how to do? Is there any other way?

```
@Aspect
public class SomeAspect {

    private static SomeObject someObject = null;

    @Pointcut("something")
    public void somePoint() {
    }

    @Before("somePoint()")
    public void beforeSomePoint() {
    }

    @After("somePoint()")
    public void afterSomePoint() {
        SomeAspect.someObject.hello();
    }

    public void waitForEvent(SomeEvent event) {
        SomeAspect.someObject = event.getObject();
    }
}
```